# Mostrar y ocultar varios ion-card mediante un botón

Tags: ionic, botón, ionic3

Buenas!!
En Ionic 3.9.2 estoy usando el siguiente comando para que mediante un botón aparezca y desaparezca un  
En el html:

```
<button ion-button block (click)="accion1()"> Botón </button>
<ion-card *ngIf="ocultar1">
   <ion-card-header>
     Título              
   </ion-card-header>
   <ion-card-content>
     Contenido
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

y en el ts:

```
export class Page { 
public ocultar1: boolean = false;
accion1(){
this.ocultar1 = !this.ocultar1;
}}
```

y la verdad es que me funciona perfectamente.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer que un botón haga aparecer varios  y desaparecer independientemente si están visibles o no?**

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Podrías dar un ejemplo mas descriptivo lo que quieres conseguir? Si repites varias veces el elemento `ion-card` y presionas el botón `accion1()` te desaparece y aparece los elementos a la vez... pero creo que no es eso ya que sería bastante simple... :)

Comment: Perdona si no me he explicado mejor.
Realmente lo que busco es que al pulsar el botón la primera vez ejecute una cosa (mostrar todos los <ion-card>) y cuando pulse de nuevo haga otra cosa (ocultar todos los <ion-card>).

Comment: Perdón... era un enlace equivocado... mira si es esto lo que quieres: [ver ejemplo](https://embed.plnkr.co/z4p6YB/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es cierto que funciona tu código, pero mi idea de base está más enfocada a esto:
https://embed.plnkr.co/39dVQqnYD0WZYRrMSocr/
cada botón muestra/oculta un ion-card, pero quiero que un botón concreto muestre todos o los oculte.
Si implemento el código actual solo conseguiría cambiar de true a false y viceversa la ocultación, y mi idea es que todos pasen o a true o a false.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que he hecho en el siguiente ejemplo:

1. Todos los botones al inicio están desactivados por defecto (`botón acción`)
2. El botón Activar/Desactivar (`botón general`) está al inicio en el estado `ACTIVAR TODOS`
3. En cuando estén **todos** los botones (1-4) activados cambia el estado `botón acción` a `DESACTIVAR TODOS` automáticamente y lo mismo funciona viceversa.

Te dejo el ejemplo:

<kbd>[Ver Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/o3GAv0vdovlsttq41hCH/)</kbd>

```
<button ion-button block (click)="acciontodos()"> {{ !ocultartodos ? 'Activar Todos' : 'Desactivar Todos' }} </button>
```

```
ocultar1: boolean     = false;
ocultar2: boolean     = false;
ocultar3: boolean     = false;
ocultar4: boolean     = false;    
ocultartodos: boolean = false;    

accion1() {        
  this.ocultar1 = !this.ocultar1;
  this.checkActiveButton();
}

accion2() {        
  this.ocultar2 = !this.ocultar2;
  this.checkActiveButton();
}

accion3() {        
  this.ocultar3 = !this.ocultar3;
  this.checkActiveButton();
}

accion4() {        
  this.ocultar4 = !this.ocultar4;
  this.checkActiveButton();
}

checkActiveButton() {

  if ( this.ocultar1 && this.ocultar2 && this.ocultar3 && this.ocultar4 ) {
    this.ocultartodos = true;
  }
  else if ( !this.ocultar1 && !this.ocultar2 && !this.ocultar3 && !this.ocultar4 ) {
    this.ocultartodos = false;
  }
}

acciontodos() {

  if ( this.ocultartodos === false ) {
    this.ocultar1     = true;
    this.ocultar2     = true;
    this.ocultar3     = true;
    this.ocultar4     = true;
  }
  else {
    this.ocultar1     = false;
    this.ocultar2     = false;
    this.ocultar3     = false;
    this.ocultar4     = false;
  }

  this.ocultartodos = !this.ocultartodos;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! funcionó!!